# tree menu with sub menus in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to create tree menu with sub menus using database table results,this is a big process,I'll explain it briefly,

[image]

dkw,keels super, mobitel in the company table then I need to get branches from branches table which are related to company using company id,company id is foreign key in branches table,I need full code in codeigniter according to the MVC architecture,I need immediate help

Comment: just extract the data from database in an array format, then leave all upto your jquery

Comment: I'am new to codeigniter,can you explain me a code